# How can I remove the previous owner Adm account. So I can make changes to my P.C. Brought it from a pawn shop

Tags: accounts

Need to remove User. I bought this P.C from a pawn shop , and, it still had a Adm, user account attached. Therefore I can't make any changes to the P.C. Was hoping that you all could help me with that?

Comment: Is the administrator account in Windows, or before Windows loads (i.e. in the BIOS)?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Why are you assuming it is Windows?

Answer (score 4):

I would reinstall Ubuntu. It would be pretty silly to recustomized the current Ubuntu to your needs. You reinstall by downloading the ISO, and wiping the disk in installation.

Comment: You can also use this post which advises booting into recovery mode and changing the password if you do not need to completely reinstall.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: I should add though that @CollDue96 is right: reinstalling is your most clean and advisable method, but in the event you were in a hurry, you could just reset the password. Good luck!

Comment: @GradyDeanDanielsJr. You really should wipe it. There could be malware on it for all we know.

Comment: @AndroidDev is wiping the disk enough, or should you format it?

Comment: @CollDue96 They are one in the same. If you want to be technical, he should "Rewrite the partition table" which will destroy any and all data on there.

Comment: However, simply selecting "erase disk and install Ubuntu" during the install will do just that.